# Запрос на сервер с помощью volley

Tags: java, android, json

Нужно сделать запрос, и отправить масив params

```
     "postData": {
        "mimeType": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "text": "quantity[26077:3AYToyOntpOjU1O3M6MjoiODQiO2k6NTY7czoyOiI4NiI7fQ==]=5&remove=&checkout_customer[address_id]=0&register=0&checkout_customer[main_firstname]=test&checkout_customer[main_telephone]=5555555555&checkout_customer[main_email]=test:40test.test&checkout_customer[main_city]=test&checkout_customer[main_address_1]=test&checkout_customer[main_comment]=&checkout_customer[main_lastname]=&checkout_customer[main_fax]=&checkout_customer[main_company]=&checkout_customer[main_company_id]=&checkout_customer[main_tax_id]=&checkout_customer[main_address_2]=&checkout_customer[main_postcode]=&checkout_customer[main_country_id]=&checkout_customer[main_zone_id]=0&shipping_address_same=1&simple_create_order=&simple_step=&simple_step_next=&simple_errors=",
        "params": [
          {
          quantity[26077:YToyOntpOjU1O3M6MjoiODQiO2k6NTY7czoyOiI4NiI7fQ==]
            "name": "quantity[26077:3AYToyOntpOjU1O3M6MjoiODQiO2k6NTY7czoyOiI4NiI7fQ==]",
            "value": "5"
          },
          {
            "name": "remove",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "checkout_customer[address_id]",
            "value": "0"
          },
          {
            "name": "register",
            "value": "0"
          },
          {
            "name": "checkout_customer[main_firstname]",
            "value": "test"
          },
          {
            "name": "checkout_customer[main_telephone]",
            "value": "5555555555"
          },
          {
            "name": "checkout_customer[main_email]",
            "value": "test:40test.test"
          },
          {
            "name": "checkout_customer[main_city]",
            "value": "test"
          },
          {
            "name": "checkout_customer[main_address_1]",
            "value": "test"
          },
          {
            "name": "checkout_customer[main_comment]",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "checkout_customer[main_lastname]",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "checkout_customer[main_fax]",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "checkout_customer[main_company]",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "checkout_customer[main_company_id]",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "checkout_customer[main_tax_id]",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "checkout_customer[main_address_2]",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "checkout_customer[main_postcode]",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "checkout_customer[main_country_id]",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "checkout_customer[main_zone_id]",
            "value": "0"
          },
          {
            "name": "shipping_address_same",
            "value": "1"
          },
          {
            "name": "simple_create_order",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "simple_step",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "simple_step_next",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "simple_errors",
            "value": ""
          }
        ]
      }
    },
```

как это сделать с помощью volley?